# Python: How to create a list out of txt with n lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `test.txt` file containing `n` lines, with one element per line, like this:

```
0.1234
0.2341
0.3412
0.4123
...
```

I want to import this file into a list, so that the list looks like this:

```
l = [0.1234, 0.2341, 0.3412, 0.4123]
```

Please note: the file has hundreds of lines.

Comment: *The test.txt file has like about hundreds of lines*. Not that that is all that many (worry when you have millions instead), but why do you need to have all those numbers in a list. You probably can process them *as you read them* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the file and it will be traversed by line by default. Convert the result to float:

```
l =  [ float(line) for line in open('file.txt') ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = open('test.txt').readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
w=open('test.text').readlines()
```

or

```
b=[line for line in open('test.text')]
print b
```